# How to backup MySQL database on Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, backup, wamp

I have WampServer 2.0 that is installed on Windows on my laptop.

I'm running on it an application that I wrote. The application is working with MySQL database.

I would like to make backups of this database periodically.

How this can be done ?

How could I define cron on Windows ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Comment: Hi, you can simply backup your MySQL Server databases automatically with the help of MySQLBackupFTP, check it https://mysqlbackupftp.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rough equivalent of `crontab -e` for Windows is the `at` command, as in:

```
at 22:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F C:\path\to\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe ...
```

Running the `at` command by itself lists the tasks you've created using `at`.

The [mysqldump documentation is here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: I agree with Ruel.  'at' is a very neat app I never knew existed!  Got a +1 from me too.  It would be an even better answer if you gave a full example rather than the '...'.  After I figure it out I'll update your answer.  ;)

Comment: FYI, while trying to running 'at' on Windows with cygwin, it told me that it was deprecated and to use schtasks.exe instead

Answer (score 8):

The most popular way to backup MySQL database is to use mysqldump:

1. Open a Windows command line.
2. Specify the directory to mysqldump utility

   `cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"`
3. Create a dump of your MySQL database.

`mysqldump.exe --user=YourUserName --password=YourPassword --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="Pathdump.sql" --databases "DatabaseName"`

Also, there are a lot of third-party tools, which can perform MySQL backups automatically on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -uroot -ppwd --opt db1 > /sqldata/db1.sql
mysqldump -uroot -ppwd --opt db2 > /sqldata/db2.sql

cd /sqldata/
tar -zcvf sqldata.tgz *.sql
cd /scripts/
perl emailsql.pl
```

http://paulbradley.tv/38/

Comment: -1 He just mentioned, he's on windows. The word `Windows` was mentioned 4 times including in the tag.

Comment: Additionally, you could check out: http://developedtraffic.com/2005/02/26/cron-and-database-backups/

Comment: Cygwin is not installed on Windows by default.