# How to find MySQL backup script/command on Linux machine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Ubuntu box that performs a database dump on all the databases in MySQL server multiple times a day. I need to find the source of these dumps and stop them. I have no idea where to even start looking for this. Any ideas?

Comment: look at cron Jobs for all user

Comment: I did - no cron jobs at all

Comment: If it's not a cron then you need to talk to the person who is obviously invoking the mysqldump command. Which user owns the created dump files?

Comment: The thing is it was a previous developer who set it up and that box has only one account that everyone uses... so there's sadly no clarity from that side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Answer (score 0):

See tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-backup-mysql-databases-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

One of the most common ways of backing up with MySQL is to use a command called "`mysqldump`".