# Export MySQL dump from AWS RDS via AWS Command Line

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to get a MySQL backup from the AWS RDS automated. I figured using AWS Command Line would be beneficial and I could use crontab on EC2 Red Hat to automate the trigger of the event.

Now the problem: How can I connect to the RDS, backup the MySQL, place it on EC2 or make a copy to S3 and let it run each night.

I am new to the AWS Command Line. Please be free to drop of suggestions and code snippets.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Answer (score 7):

- On EC2 instance make a cron.sh file and put below content.

  `mysqldump -h RDS_ENPOINT -u MASTER_USER_DATABASE -p DATABASE_NAME > /backup/bkp.$(date +%Y%m%d).sql`
- Create Other file move_to_s3.sh and put below content

  ```
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "starting upload to s3 ..."
      TODAY=$(date +%Y%m%d);
      month=$(date +"%m");
      year=$(date +"%Y");
      bucket="mybkp"
      file="$year/$month/bkp.$TODAY.tar"
      filepath="/backup/bkp.$TODAY.tar"
      resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
      contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
      dateValue=`date -R`
      stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
      s3Key=AKIAI7BE3RKNSsdfsdfASF
      s3Secret=sdfksdfkJsdfgd76sdfkljhdfsdfsdfsdf
      signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`;

      RESPONSE=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -s -X PUT -T "${filepath}" \
              -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
              -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
              -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
              -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
              https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file} -o /dev/null $1);

      echo $RESPONSE;
      if [ $RESPONSE -ne 200 ] ; then
          echo "There was an issue in transfering DB dbbackup file to S3. Noticed Error Code: $RESPONSE" | mail -s "Issue on transfer to S3" test@gmail.com;
      else
          rm $filepath;
      fi
      echo "finished upload."`
  ```

Set both in cron in half hour distance!

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

you can make backups directly from EC2 using mysqldump.

1. Edit *Security Group* of your RDS instance, *Inbound rules*:

   Type: Mysql/Aurora

   Protocol: TCP

   Port Range: 3306

   **Source: Custom EC2_SECURITY_GROUP_ID**

   Example (Source: Custom sg_451caa43)
2. Connect to EC2 instance with SSH:

   `[MacBook-Pro: user]$ ssh -i keypair.pem ec2-user@PUBLIC_IP`
3. In EC2 instance install mysql-client:

   `[ec2-user@ip-170-10-20-30]$ sudo yum install mysql`
4. Try **mysqldump** command

`[ec2-user@ip-170-10-20-30]$ mysqldump -h RDS_ENPOINT -u MASTER_USER_DATABASE -p DATABASE_NAME > backup.sql`

```
[ec2-user@ip-170-10-20-30]$ mysqldump -h db_test.cdsludsd.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u admin -p my_database > backup_my_database.sql
```

4. Create cron job.

Comment: Will this be fast enough? I have around 100GB of data on a single Database and i have around 5 Databases like this how long do you think will this take ?

Answer (score 0):

We should avoid exporting and uploading to s3 in 2 steps.

For larger DB, I would suggest using the below command to upload file to S3 directly without occupying the local space

```
mysqldump -h [db_hostname] -u [db_user] -p[db_passwd] [databasename] | aws s3 cp - s3://[s3_bucketname]/[mysqldump_filename]
```

e.g.

```
mysqldump -h $HOST -u $USER -p $PASSWORD $DB_NAME --routines --single-transaction | gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/exportfile.sql.gz
```