# phpmyadmin export file size

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export

This question relates to the file size resulting from phpmyadmin export.

I am exporting a table using phpmyadmin export.

I had exported the table with 10M rows a few days back.

Now the table has 15M rows. Now, when I export that same table again, the resulting table1.sql file size is **less** than before. I am using exactly the same export settings (the max query size, etc.)

I have not used compression either time. I am exporting to a flat .sql query file containing 'INSERT INTO' queries.

Is this possible ? Perhaps someone can shed light on the situation.

Couple of things that may be relevant -
- phpmyadmin shows a row count smaller than the exact row count next to 'Dump some row(s):'

(Unfortunately, I can't attach either export file - they are just too big.)

Comment: Look in the PHP error log, or check the last few lines of the file to see if it completed or failed

Comment: Good suggestion. No errors there. phpmyadmin displays message 'completed successfully', so I assume that there were no errors encountered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Comment: Better use mysqldump ***`mysqldump -p -u username DATABASE table --where="datefield >= 'start date' AND datefield <= 'end date')`***

Answer (score 1):

PHPmyadmin is loaded through Apache, which has a `max_execution_time` usually configured to 60 seconds. If PHPMyadmin takes more time than `max_execution_time` then phpmyadmin task wont be complete.

You can increase the `max_execution_time` to maximum time, but it will affect your every website served through Apache on this server.

***Recommended is, export data through `mysqldump` tool in terminal***

`mysqldump -p -u username DATABASE`

If you want to export particular table
`mysqldump -p -u username DATABASE table`

If you want to add where condition to export

`mysqldump -p -u username DATABASE table --where="Yourfield >= 'start date' AND Yourfield <= 'end date')`