# importing csv into mysql via cron

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cron

I am a complete noob when it comes to mysql databases.

What i want to achieve - is this - i have a sap b1 database and i am going to be exporting data from the sql server out to a csv - from there i will send this csv through to my web server.

Now what i want to do is to load up the csv into a mysql database on a scheduled basis (daily) via a cron job.

Here is the data that i will likely have in multiple csvs:

- orders
- invoices
- credits
- payments

Would i create a database for each or have them all within one database within phpmyadmin?
Also - let's take orders for example - would i create two tables - one for the order header information and another for order lines?

An example of the invoices csv would be the following format:

- customernumber
- customername
- invoicenumber
- purchaseordernumber
- documentdate
- freightamount
- productcode
- productname
- barcode
- quantity
- price ex tax
- price inc tax
- RRP price
- tax amount
- doc total inc tax

Once in the tables - i will then go about developing a secure website/ application for my company that will be used by internal staff as well as customers.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Regards
Rick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Comment: @e4c5 I need to add a cron / load data so there are 2

Comment: something in this mess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron+mysql

Comment: @drew, add another section to the dupe target? Will do

Comment: @e4c5 well if you already voted then a url for me

Comment: Frankly it is just too broad and will get Roomba'd prob

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at CSV files is that each is a table:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
Value1,Value2,Value3
...,...,...
```

->

```
Header1 | Header2 | Header3
---------------------------
Value1  | Value2  | Value3 
...     | ...     | ...
```

In mysql, a single database can have many tables. So for your example, you may want to have a single database with a table for each CSV file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
OK - one CSV = one table

Comment: Do you have an example of the script required to import a CSV into a table? let's say for example - code, name, qty is the CSV - I would then set up a table with those exact headers in that order.

Comment: The internet has more examples than I can offer. Try searching "csv mysql" :)