# mysqldump in sh script not working

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, sh

I've got a sh script to backup a database-server.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> --all-databases --single-transaction --opt > /home/backup/h_157_2-1.sql
rsync -zrp --partial /home/backup/h_157_2-1.sql root@<server-ip>:/home/backup/H_157_2/
```

When I execute those two command on their own in the command line, they work as expected and I get a .sql file with content. But when I execute the script the file only contains this:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

I already tried to change up the order of the options or leave out the `--opt` but the result was still the same. So what could cause the command to not work in the script?

Comment: you have an error in your mysqldump syntax, that is why the file is populated with the result of just `mysqldump` command

Comment: @ElzoValugi what is the error? And why does it work when I copy the command to the comand line and execute it?

Comment: try `-A` instead of `--all-databases`. it worked for me

Comment: @ElzoValugi I tried that but the result is still the same.

Comment: how are you using the password? try `--password=yourPassword` or try only with `-p` and manually input it just to exclude this part

Comment: @ElzoValugi --password=yourPassword had the same result. just -p didn't even ask for the password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128798/discussion-between-elzo-valugi-and-docrattie).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to resolve the initial problem. Even with the help from Elzo Valugi  in chat the result was still the same: Excecuted on command line the mysqldump worked finde. Excecuted in the script I got the same msg all the time. (see initial question).

To resolve it I built a workaround to dump every database on it's own.

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in /var/lib/mysql/*/; 
do 
  dir=${dir%*/}
  mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> ${dir##*/} --single-transaction --opt > /home/backup/h_157_2_${dir##*/}.sql
  rsync -zrp --partial /home/backup/h_157_2_${dir##*/}.sql root@<server-ip>:/home/backup/H_157_2/
done;
```

With this I loop through all the directorys in the mysql storage directory, cut them down to the dir-name and use that for the mysqldump. This puts every database in its own file. I think this could be resolved to combine them all to one, but for my needs I'm fine with different files.