# how to take efficient mysql data back using php?

Tags: php, mysql, backup

How can i take myasql data backup efficiently.

I am using Adminer Script to take backup manually. When it comes cron job or auto script i cant able to take backup. Please help me to resolve my problem.

When i am using the Following Query i am getting the error while import the file

```
SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/my_table.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

**Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '131 1 02/01/2016 1200 sales debit 43 223 6 31/12/2015 0 production debit 1 S' at line 1**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Comment: When i am trying to import its show the error!. Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '131 1 02/01/2016 1200 sales debit 43 223 6 31/12/2015 0 production debit 1 S' at line 1

Comment: I don't think you can type 2 FROM clauses...