# mysqldump creates 0 byte sql file from Cron Jobs in cPanel

Tags: mysql, cron, cpanel

I have zero bytes sql file (or gz) from this Cron Jobs command in cPanel (only cPanel Cron Jobs):

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=localhost DATABASENAME > /PATH/FILENAME.sql
```

Many questions checked but nothing found!
I check these path for mysqldump:

```
/usr/mysql/bin/mysqldump
usr/bin/mysqldump
mysqldump
```

**UPDATE:**
Make .sh file and run that from Cron Jobs. Everythings OK.

```
#!/bin/bash\
/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=localhost DBNAME > /home/CPANELUSER/public_html/FOLDER/FILENAME.sql
```

Comment: Add `2> /tmp/backup-error.log` to the end of the command.  That should create an error log with an explanation of the problem.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I saw that without error, but write that code into .sh file and run from Cron Jobs ... everythings OK. Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Comment: @e4c5 Solved by UPDATE. Thanks

Comment: still an unscalabe and unwieldly approach

Comment: @e4c5 Only Cron Jobs in cPanel, not PHP codes in website. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make .sh file and run that from Cron Jobs. Everythings OK.

```
#!/bin/bash\
/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=localhost DBNAME > /home/CPANELUSER/public_html/FOLDER/FILENAME.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in BlueHost cPanel:
/usr/bin/mysqldump -uUSERNAME -p'PASSWORD' DBNAME > /home4/CPANELUSER/FILENAME_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M`.sql

You can check error by adding this at the end (logs is name of an existing folder):

> > logs/$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M").log 2>&1