# Set Cron Auto Backup mysql Databases

Tags: mysql

i have try to set cron file for get auto backup to all my database table.

i was using following mysqldump command :

```
sudo mysqldump -u username -p password --all-databases | gzip > mysqldb_`date +%F`.sql.gz
```

but it's show following error :

> mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'password' when selecting the database

any other option to get automatic mysql database backup

thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Comment: first time i have set cron file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo mysqldump -u root -p<mysql-password> --all-databases | gzip > mysqldb_date +%F.sql.gz
```

Comment: add space between -p and <mysql-password>

Comment: it's not show the error but generated file content in mysqldump command list `Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS] For more options, use mysqldump --help`

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> --password[=password], -p[password]
> ```
>
> The password to use when connecting to the server. **If you use the
>   short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and
>   the password**. If you omit the password value following the --password
>   or -p option on the command line, mysql prompts for one.

Comment: i was enter password without space it's given following error: gzip: +%F.sql.gz: No such file or directory
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the first message (second one is self-explanatory) but you should probably store the file in some specific path, not in whatever working directory the scripts happens to run at.

Comment: command run successfully it's not show any error but generated file show follwoinig text                                                                                       Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help