# Bash script to run mysqldump to take regular backup of a single table with rows create 1 day before

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

Below is the BASH(Version 4.1.2) script i have placed on cronjob which runs daily at 23:59 to backup a table with records created on that particur day

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db 
--no-create-info databasename salestable1 
--where="acctstarttime 
LIKE '2016-12-28%'" >  /dbbackup/`date +%F`-salestable1.sql
```

Here the problem is i have to manually change the date part `LIKE '2016-12-28%'` inside *mysql execute command* manually.

How to construct the current script so that it can backup the table with records created on particular day withouthaving to change date manually ?

### solution for my case

```
sys_date=`date +%F -d '-1 day'`
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db   \ 
--no-create-info ctradius radacct     \
--where="acctstarttime LIKE '${sys_date}%'" >      \
/backup/freeradius/radacct-`date +%F -d '-1 day'`.sql
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automated or regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/automated-or-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db --no-create-info databasename salestable1 --where="acctstarttime LIKE '$(date +%F)%'" > /dbbackup/databasename/`date +%F`-salestable1.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to introduce one variable, i.e:

**The script:**

```
root@h1 ~# cat backup_table.sh

#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%F)
echo "/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db --no-create-info databasename salestable1 --where="acctstarttime LIKE \'${DATE}%\'" >  /dbbackup/`date +%F`-salestable1.sql"
```

**Launched script with dynamic date:**

```
root@h1 ~# bash backup_table.sh
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db --no-create-info databasename salestable1 --where=acctstarttime LIKE '2016-12-28%' >  /dbbackup/2016-12-28-salestable1.sql
```

Comment: You cannot wrap quotes like in your `echo` statement.

Comment: Running `date +%F` a second time to create the date stamp in the file name is useless, since you already have this value in a variable.

Comment: hi triplee, that was just a purpose to verify if the date is printed correctly,I believe it could be resolved in similar way. Still, satch_boogie can improve it

Comment: You have to put `\"` inside the double quotes to get a literal double quote.  Alternatively, don't put quotes around the argument to `echo` (but understand the perils).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
_cmd="/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db 
--no-create-info databasename salestable1 
--where=\"acctstarttime 
LIKE '$(date +%F)%'\" >  /dbbackup/`date +%F`-salestable1.sql"

echo $_cmd

eval $_cmd
```

and if you exec it, output like is this

wzq@~ >_ ./foo.sh

/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db --no-create-info databasename salestable1 --where="acctstarttime LIKE '2016-12-29%'" > /dbbackup/2016-12-29-salestable1.sql

./foo.sh: line 9: /dbbackup/2016-12-29-salestable1.sql: No such file or directory