# mysqldump will cause "too many connections" error on client

Tags: mysql

I'm running a MySQL (5.7) with Docker container, two clients are connecting to it with several operations per second, written in Spring-Data-JPA. Over time the DB is getting large with around 21GB of data.

I tried to setup a databack up mechanism by running `mysqldump`, but when running this cmd now, MySQL DB will basically stop responding, and the client will report errors like `too many connections`. Wondering what's a reliable and effective approach to back up data without impacting the performance too much?

Comment: Maybe you need to increase how many connections your server can handle. What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` indicate for activity?

Comment: A `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` displays 20 rows, of course this is while I'm not running the mysqldump, does this look ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automated or regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/automated-or-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)