# How to create backup of one database into another database using php

Tags: php, database, backup

I want to create backup of my website database in which is in MySQL in another database on regular basis , is it possible to do it using php

Already tried exporting database using php but requirement is something else

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. Would you want to? Probably not. There are tools for this. Simplest being mysqldump cli tool which you could run on a cron schedule if you wished.

Comment: which another database are you planning to choose? It's possible but It will require plenty of work.

Comment: I have a database with name A which contain all the data and a database B which is empty i want to copy all data from database A to database B using PHP specifically

Comment: To add to Jonnix comment that this might be a bad idea: You would need to open two database connections, transferring all data, probably while one database is live, and the connections could go down. You would have to build in a lot of checks to make sure you actually get a good copy. Simply dumping the database, and importing it into the other database is simpler, and can be done with PHP.

Comment: You could also consider db replication as a solution.

Comment: I think you can stop mysql services and copy data folder for backup

Comment: That would depend on the engine being used I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automated or regular backup of mysql data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/automated-or-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Answer (score 0):

I think `mysqldump` is what you're looking for.

Export database A to SQL file to import to database B:

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=dbauser --password=dbapassword dba_name > /path/to/store/dba.sql
```

Import database A dump into database B:

```
cp /path/to/store/dba.sql | mysql --host-localhost --user=dbbuser --password=dbbpassword dbb_name
```

You can wrap these commands in a call to `system()` in a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$host_name = "localhost";
$user_name= "root";
$password= "";
$database1 = "database_name";
$database2 = "second_database_name";
$con1 = mysqli_connect($host_name ,$user_name,$password,$database1);
$con2 = mysqli_connect($host_name ,$user_name,$password,$database2);

mysqli_select_db($con1,$database1)
mysqli_select_db($con2,$database2)

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($con1, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($con2, $sql);
```